# How should duplicate keywords be handled when using Aho-Corasick?

Tags: aho-corasick

When building the tree, how do you handle duplicates in the list of keywords?
Should you ensure the list is free from duplicates before tree building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should avoid it. Simple because it gives for the dupes different states it makes the automata bigger and longer to search.

Comment: @erotavlas:If my answer is helpful please consider to accept it and/or upvote it! Thank you!